# How to configure a many to many relationship with primary key too in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

This is what i am trying to achieve :

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()      
                    .HasMany(u => u.Following)
                    .WithMany(u => u.Followers)
                    .Map(m =>
                            {
                                m.ToTable("FollowTables");
                                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                                m.MapRightKey("FollowId");
                            });
```

In application user class, i have configured following and followers like this:

```
public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Following { get; set; }
public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; }
```

follow table should be something like this:

```
 public class FollowTable
 {
    [Key]
    public int autoId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? FollowId { get; set; }
 }
```

autoId is primary key and UserId and FollowId both are foreign key to ApplicationUser class where UserId is user's own id and FollowId are the ids which user is following.Its data could be following:

```
  autoId  UserId  FollowId
   1        4        11
   2        4        12
   3        4        13
```

Now, i problem is when i update database through pmc, it is creating two database tables one is FollowTables with column (USerId, FollowId) and one is FollowTables1(autoId, USerId, FollowId).

If i remove this line from applicationDbContext class:

```
public DbSet<FollowTable> FollowTables { get; set; }
```

then its creating only one table but with no primary key.

please someone help me out . how to properly configure UserId and followId as foreign key and these two should map to ApplicationUser's Id.
I want to use those Collection's following and Followers too.how to do it.

Comment: Could you show your `ApplicationUser` class? There might be some convention stuff happening. Also, why do you expect `FollowId` to be nullable?

Comment: public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
     public string Address { get; set; }
        
       public ApplicationUser()
        { 
        //    this.FollowTables = new HashSet<FollowTable>();
        }
        //     public virtual ICollection<FollowTable> FollowTables { get; set; }

        // calculated properties
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Following { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide if you want to work with an entity that represents the junction table or not. If you don't need to add any other properties to that table, excluding the FKs, then I suggest you don't map the junction table as entity. It is going to be more easy for you due to Entity Framework will handle that table for you.

Now if you really need to map that table then you need to delete many-to-many fluent api configuration and change the type of your navigation properties:

```
public ICollection<FollowTable> Following { get; set; }
public ICollection<FollowTable> Followers { get; set; }
```

That is going to create two one-to-many relationships with the junction table, an explicit representation of a many-to-many relationship. To do that you also need to do some changes in that entity:

```
public class FollowTable
{
  [Key]
  public int autoId { get; set; }

  public int UserId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("User")]
  public ApplicationUser User{ get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Follow")]
  public int? FollowId { get; set; }
  public ApplicationUser Follow{ get; set; }
}
```

Also, I don't think `FollowId` Fk property should be a nullable FK, because you want to represent a relationship between two persons.

If you ask my opinion about what option you should take, I suggest you don't map the junction table if you are going to have only those properties.

Comment: obliged! thnkx for the help got it working @octavioccl